# What did Brienne write about Jaime?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* S08E06, Brienne

> becomes the Lord Commander of the Kingsguard.

She then opens the book which we saw in earlier seasons which holds the accomplishments of other Kingsguard.

> Brienne opens up Jaime's page and begins to write his accomplishments.

What did she write about Jaime? Has anyone transcribed it? I managed to see about his vow to Catelyn Stark, his siege of Riverrun and his promise to fight for the living.

Comment: I know something that ISN'T in there-no mention of WHY he killed the Mad king, even tho Brienne and Brandon were the only 2 other people who know....

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Jaime's entry (as written by Barristan Selmy then Jaime himself) read as follows:

[image: The page from the book written below]

> ## Ser Jaime Lannister
>
> Squired for Barriston Selmy against the Kingswood Outlaws.
> Knighted and named to the Kingsguard in his Sixteenth year for valour in the field: At the Sack of Kings Landing, murdered his King, Aerys the second at the foot of the Iron Throne:
> Pardoned by King Robert Baratheon:
> Thereafter known as the Kingslayer:
> After the murder of King Joffrey I by Tyrion Lannister served under King Tommen I:

Brienne added the following:

[image: Part 1 of Brienne's writing quoted below]
[image: Part 2 of Brienne's writing quoted below]
[image: Part 3 of Brienne's writing quoted below]

> Captured in the field at the Whispering Wood:
> Set free by Lady Catelyn Stark in return for an oath to find and return her two daughters:
> Lost his-- *[text lost by cut]*
> Took Riverrun from the Tully rebels, without loss of life.
> Lured the Unsullied into attacking Casterly Rock, sacrificing his childhood home in service to a greater strategy.
> Outwitted the Targaryen forces to seize Highgarden. Fought at the Battle of the Goldroad bravely, narrowly escaping death by dragonfire.
> Pledged himself to the forces of men and rode north to join them at Winterfell, alone. Faced the Army of the Dead, and defended the castle against impossible odds until the defeat of the Night King. Escaped imprisonment and rode south in an attempt to save the capital from destruction.
> Died protecting his Queen.

Presumably, the text lost by camera-cut finished as *"Lost his hand to Bolton forces during the War of the Five Kings"* or something to that effect.

Comment: Conjecture: *Lost his* sword hand whilst a prisoner of Locke....?

Comment: Was that when he lost his hand in the timeline?

Comment: @T.E.D. yes. Jamie was set free by Catelyn, captured by Locke (along with Brienne), had his hand chopped off, freed by Bolton, returned to free Brienne, goes on to Kings Landing. But Jaime himself chose to everything between between becoming Kingsguard to Bobby B and Joffrey's death, so the timeline of the page is messed up. :/

Comment: In a side shot you can barely make out that she's writing the word "right" after the text "Lost his-- ". So I believe it's supposed to say "Lost his right hand[...]"

Answer (score 11):

It's never all shown in one moment, but you can piece it together based on two:

[image: Screenshot of Brienne's writing]
[image: Screenshot of Brienne's writing]